# WPF: Binding List to ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, observablecollection

I have a class:

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<B> bList { get; set; } 

    public void AddB(B b)
    {
        bList.Add(b);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("bList");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

And a binding (DataContext of UserControl is an instance of A):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=bList}" />
```

Elements are shown, the ListBox is not updated after new object is added to List

After changing list to ObservableCollection and removing the NotifyPropertyChanged handler everything works.

Why the list is not working?

Comment: Please post your real code... The code you posted can't work, even with an ObservableCollection. And the NotifyPropertyChanged changes nothing, since you're not using it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<strike>Your property has to be `public`, or the binding engine won't be able to access it.</strike>

---

EDIT:

> After changing list to ObservableCollection and removing the NotifyPropertyChanged handler everything works.

That's precisely why the `ObservableCollection<T>` class was introduced... `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which allows it to notify the UI when an item is added/removed/replaced. `List<T>` doesn't trigger any notification, so the UI can't detect when the content of the list has changed.

The fact that you raise the `PropertyChanged` event does refresh the binding, but then it realizes that it's the same instance of `List<T>` as before, so it reuses the same `ICollectionView` as the `ItemsSource`, and the content of the `ListBox` isn't refreshed.

Comment: Thanks, it is public, I forgot to write it in the code. Now the code is changed

Comment: Thanks explaining why `ObservableCollection` is useful in data binding.

Answer (score 0):

First thought is that you're trying to bind to a private member. That certainly doesn't seem right.

Comment: Thanks, it is public, I forgot to write it in the code. Now the code is changed

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that, although you are notifying the binding framework that the property has changed, the actual value of the property remains the same.  That is to say that although the listbox may reevaluate the value of its ItemsSource binding, it will find that it is still the same *object instance* as previously.  For example, imagine that the listbox reacts by to the property changed event somehow similar to the below.

```
private void OnItemsSourceBindingChanged()
{
    var newValue = this.EvaluateItemsSourceBinding();
    if (newValue != this.ItemsSource) //it will be equal, as its still the same list
    {
        this.AddNewItems();
    }
}
```

In your example, this would mean that it would not reevaluate the items.

Note: I do not *know* how the listbox works with the ItemsSource property - I'm just speculating!

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollections send [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668629.aspx) events not PropertyChanged events

Answer (score 0):

By signaling

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("bList");
```

you are basically saying you have a new ***list*** object, not that the content of the List has changed.

If you Change the type to ObservableCollection, the collections automatically sends

```
CollectionChanged
```

notifications that the collection ***items*** have changed, which is what you want.